# Spring MVC Image upload Integration test using Mockmvc and JSON failure

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I was trying to upload an image using my test class. I am using JSON to send the data using mockmvc.I am trying to add a Image from my PC to JSON. I am using link of the image to add it to the JSON.
Below I've given my test portion:

```
    @Test
    public void updateAccountImage() throws Exception{
        Account updateAccount = new Account();
        updateAccount.setPassword("test");
        updateAccount.setNamefirst("test");
        updateAccount.setNamelast("test");
        updateAccount.setEmail("test");
        updateAccount.setCity("test");
        updateAccount.setCountry("test");
        updateAccount.setAbout("test");
        BufferedImage img;
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg"));
        WritableRaster raster = img .getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] testImage = data.getData();
        updateAccount.setImage(testImage);

        when(service.updateAccount(any(Account.class))).thenReturn(
                updateAccount);

        MockMultipartFile image = new MockMultipartFile("json", "", "application/json", "{\"image\": \"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg\"}".getBytes());

        mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/accounts/test/updateImage")
                        .file(image))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

And here is the controller portion:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/{username}/updateImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<AccountResource> updateAccountImage(@PathVariable("username") String username,
        @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image) {
    AccountResource resource =new AccountResource();

      if (!image.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        resource.setImage(image.getBytes());
                        resource.setUsername(username);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
    Account account = accountService.updateAccountImage(resource.toAccount());
    if (account != null) {
        AccountResource res = new AccountResourceAsm().toResource(account);
        return new ResponseEntity<AccountResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<AccountResource>(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    }
}
```

But, something went wrong. My console output is below:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /accounts/test/updateImage
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[multipart/form-data]}

             Handler:
                Type = web.rest.mvc.AccountController
              Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<web.rest.resources.AccountResource> web.rest.mvc.AccountController.updateAccountImage(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile)

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 400
       Error message = Required MultipartFile parameter 'image' is not present
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

I am assuming there is a problem with adding my image to JSON. Could anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial parameter of the *MockMultipartFile* is the name of your file, and it must match the name of the argument inside the controller method. You need to change to *image*

```
MockMultipartFile image = new MockMultipartFile("image", "", "application/json", "{\"image\": \"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg\"}".getBytes());
```

Comment: Hi,I changed it but I'm getting a different error from this. The error is: "org.springframework.web.utill.NestedServletException:Request Processing Failed;nested exception is java.lang.illigulArgument"
I've tried different opting, also searched for the solution many place,but failed. Can you tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem in this code. The controller returns the resource that having image inside. That causing processing failed. Right code is given below:

@test portion

```
        Account updateAccount = new Account();
        updateAccount.setPassword("test");
        updateAccount.setNamefirst("test");
        updateAccount.setNamelast("test");
        updateAccount.setEmail("test");
        updateAccount.setCity("test");
        updateAccount.setCountry("test");
        updateAccount.setAbout("test");
        BufferedImage img;
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg"));
        WritableRaster raster = img .getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] testImage = data.getData();
        updateAccount.setImage(testImage);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg");
        MockMultipartFile image = new MockMultipartFile("image", fis);


          HashMap<String, String> contentTypeParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        contentTypeParams.put("boundary", "265001916915724");
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", contentTypeParams);

        when(service.updateAccountImage(any(Account.class))).thenReturn(
                updateAccount);
        mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/accounts/test/updateImage")
                .file(image)        
                    .contentType(mediaType))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Controller Portion:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/updateImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<AccountResource> updateAccountImage(@PathVariable("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("image") final MultipartFile file)throws IOException {


    AccountResource resource =new AccountResource();
                        resource.setImage(file.getBytes());
                        resource.setUsername(username);


    Account account = accountService.updateAccountImage(resource.toAccount());
    if (account != null) {
        AccountResource res = new AccountResourceAsm().toResource(account);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        return new ResponseEntity<AccountResource>(res,headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<AccountResource>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```